# How to display fields and their values from salesforce fieldset in a html table

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to display fields and their vlues from salesforce fieldset in html table. I used the code below. I am not sure how to display the field values as I have a query in the constructor of the controller to get the required records.

I tried the below within the `td` tag and `repeat` tag

```
<table id="freeze-table">
    <tr>
        <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.FieldSets.checkfieldset}"> 
            <th>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="bold" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.Fields[f].label}"/>
            </th>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.FieldSets.checkfieldset}">
            <!-- <td>
                <apex:outputField value="{!adpubs.[f.fieldpath]}" />
            </td> -->
        </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where **abclist** will contain the queried records.

I received the error message

> "Error: Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Number,
>   received Text"

Comment: What's abclist? A list or a map? Can you please post some more code, the whole `apex:repeat` section would be helpful

Comment: abclist is a list of abc object records.

Comment: <table id="freeze-table">         
          <tr>
          <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.FieldSets.checkfieldset}">
          <th><apex:outputText styleClass="bold" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.Fields[f].label}"/> </th>
          </apex:repeat>
          </tr>
          <tr> <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.FieldSets.checkfieldset}">  
      <!--  <td>  <apex:outputField value="{!adpubs.[f.fieldpath]}" />  </td>  -->
           </apex:repeat>
          </tr>       </table>

Comment: @SFDCLearner please update your question with any additional info rather than posting it in the comments.  This makes it easier to understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate through the list, and then also through each of the fields in your field set for each of the records. So your code should look something like this (haven't tested it but it should give you an idea of how to get the desired result):

```
<table id="freeze-table"> 
    <tr> 
        <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.FieldSets.checkfieldset}"> 
            <th>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="bold" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.Fields[f].label}"/>
            </th> 
        </apex:repeat>
    </tr> 
    <apex:repeat var="adpub" value="{!adpubs}">
        <tr> 
            <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Adpub__c.FieldSets.checkfieldset}"> 
                <td>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!adpub[f]}" /> 
                </td> 
            </apex:repeat> 
        </tr> 
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```